Mentioning @everyone in a Channel Message via Teams Bot
I have developed a Microsoft Teams bot using the Bot Framework that sends messages to users both in personal chat and within a channel. For some of these messages, I utilize Adaptive Cards, and I can successfully mention individual users in both personal and channel messages.
However, I am facing a challenge when trying to mention the whole team, channel, or use @everyone in a channel message. My goal is to notify all team members when the bot sends a message in a channel, ensuring that everyone receives a notification.
After some research, it seems that this functionality might not be supported in the Teams Bot Framework, but I wanted to confirm if there’s a workaround or any upcoming support for this feature.
Can you please provide guidance on how to achieve this, or confirm if it's a limitation?

Git - MS Teams 
Format cards in Teams


Currently this is not supported and a known limitation. You can suggest this feature at https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472.
